# jQuery validation: Show/hide custom elements besides the default elements

Tags: jquery, validation, callback, hide, element

What I would like to do is the following. I have an image which shows a tooltip on hover. When a field does not pass the validation, I would like to show the default error message aswell as the images' title in a new paragraph. The tooltip image should then be hidden. When the field then passes validation, the default error message should be hidden again (default behaviour), my paragraph should be hidden and the tooltip image should be shown again.

So, when a field does not pass validation:
- Default validations error message
- Tooltip images' title

And when a field does pass validation:
- Tooltip image

I got the 'failed validation' part figured out but when the field passes validation, the tooltip images' title is still shown and the tooltip image is hidden. So what I basically need is a callback to a function when some field passes validation.

This is what I've got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('form#saveform').validate({

    ignore: ":hidden",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

        var error_td = element.parent('td').next('td');
        var tooltip_img = error_td.find('img.tooltip');

        error_td.append(error);
        error_td.append('<p class="notice">' + tooltip_img.attr('oldtitle') + '</p>');

        tooltip_img.hide();

    }

});

});
```

Can anyone help me making this work?

Comment: Can you link us to a jsFiddle, or paste in the relevant html code here? It will be impossible to find the error right now if it turns out it's in your element selection.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks for your reply. it's not that this code does not work. The only thing I'm wanting to add is a method to call a function when a field is marked as valid where I would then show/hide the right elements. The above code hides the tooltip image, show the error and the images' title in the column next to the specific form field already. I just need to fix the 'valid part' which is not captured yet in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the validate plugin would have a callback when the validation is successful. Although it has callbacks to apply and remove error highlighting to/from elements.
So what you could do is:

```
$('form#saveform').validate({
  highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    // add error, hide image
  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
     // remove error, show image
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks rucsi, I've got it to work with the method you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Ah -- you want the `success` hook:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('form#saveform').validate({

        ignore: ":hidden",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

            var error_td = element.parent('td').next('td');
            var tooltip_img = error_td.find('img.tooltip');
            error_td.append(error);
            error_td.append('<p class="notice">' + tooltip_img.attr('oldtitle') + '</p>');
            tooltip_img.hide();

        }
        success: function() {
            // Your success code here...
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: I have indeed tried that but as soon as I create a success hook, it starts calling the errorPlacement function with an empty error message on all of the required fields (valid or invalid!) even when the success function is empty like in your example.